# When do you need to write a Redux Persist Migration

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I have just added redux-persist to my project and I come across redux persist migration which would is a good way of doing database like migration when you change the shape of your persisted state. My question is since I am currently doing my first version of the app when should I write the redux persist migration now or only whenever I make changes in the future version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your teams and processes work.

#### Solo developer

You can probably erase and create everything from scratch without a problem while your app is on its developing stage. This is because you don't have any users or customers with an "old" version.

Once it's in prod, you now need to consider what the transition is for your customers. Here's where you want to have a migration process. You also want the followings:

- Tests for a new customer who will be getting the new structure only
- Tests for an existing customer with an old structure, who will be migrated to the new one

#### Part of a team

If you're in an organization where you have multiple teams and/or multiple environments, you want to start viewing them as your users/customer as well. QA team is your customer, other team that depend on your service is also a customer. Which means that even if your app is on its developing stage, you cannot rely on nuking everything, but need to handle a migration process, with the tests I described before.

#### Conclusion (TL;DR:)

It depends, if you have consumers you probably want a migration process

PS: worth mentioning that this analysis is not coupled to redux persistence, but to general database structure migration. You could apply the same principles when migrating a SQL table structure

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but my question is more on the side of do you need to care about writing a migration on your first prod release where every user is a new user and there is no existing user?

Comment: As the answer above says, if you don't have any customers/users/consumers yet, then there's no value in adding a migration